# Multidimensional PHP Array to JSON Array

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json

I have this PHP Array:

```
Array
(
    [messages] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sender] => 17
                    [receiver] => 4
                    [message] => TEST 2
                    [timestamp] => 1367200891
                    [read] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [sender] => 17
                    [receiver] => 4
                    [message] => TEST 1
                    [timestamp] => 1367197661
                    [read] => 0
                )

        )

    [new_messages] => 2
)
```

It gets retrieved via an Ajax Request, using `json_encode()` to output it in PHP.

```
function getMessages(rec){
var nmsg = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        async: true,
        url: "/ps/getUserMessages.php",
        data: {'u':rec,'s00':s00,'n01':n01,'t02':t02}       
    });
    nmsg.done(function(data) {
        var json = JSON.parse(data);
        if (typeof json.messages[0].message !== 'undefined') {
            printMessage(json);
        }
    }); 
}
```

And as `printMessage()` function, for example, i need to do something like:

```
loop(){
    $("#elem").append(
          '<div>Sender: '+arrayOfValues.sender+'</div>'
         +'<div>Message: '+arrayOfValues.message+'</div>'
    );
}
```

for each Array of values.

I tried jQuery `$.each()` and also `for()` with some examples i found, but i cannot get to work.

Comment: Use serialize() and unserialize() to pass an array between php and js and back again easily.  Or you can use json_encode() on your code behind php page. then pass it back to your ajax function which can then dump that into a text box which can be posted and json decoded or you can json decode in javascript too and get an array out either way will work fine.

Comment: @Dave I think the problem is not within the encoding, but with accessing the received result.

Comment: Not seeing where the outputting to PHP is in that then as it looks from his code like he's purely attempting to handle it in JS.

Comment: @dave i said that i was using json_encode() to pass it to javascript. Read well :) The array it's there just for let you see the structure.

Comment: if your php is passing it back as JSON then just set your ajax data type to ajax `dataType: 'json'`  and then use the onsuccess function success: function(data){ and you can reference your array as just data["column"] etc so you don't have to mess around parsing json etc you can just directly loop it out. you can remove at least 7 lines of code from your overall code.

Comment: @WiS3 Undeleted it. The general consensus seemed to prefer the `for ... in` solution.

Comment: @dave Thanks for the dataType: 'json'. But success() is deprecated as i'm using jQuery 1.9.1

Comment: fair enough didn't know it was deprecated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
function printMessage(data) {
  for( var i=0; i<data.messages.length; i++ ) {
    $("#elem").append(
        '<div>Sender: ' + data.messages[i].sender + '</div>'
       +'<div>Message: ' + data.messages[i].message+ '</div>'
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to iterate over given structure you should use use following as a **printMessage**:

```
function printMessage( json ){
    for ( var i in json.messages ) {
        var currentMessage = json.messages[i];

        $("#elem").append(
          '<div>Sender: '+currentMessage.sender+'</div>'
         +'<div>Message: '+currentMessage.message+'</div>'
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't use `for(var i in ...)` for arrays. It's for `objects` and nothing else.

Comment: So this answer is a suitable solution for this case (reference: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)

Comment: @henasraf Better use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/JavaScript) as a reference instead of w3schools. Why? Have a look at [w3fools.com](http://w3fools.com/) - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for